Visual Studio: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: obj' when opening or building a .vcproj project
I'm trying to build a legacy project (dbgen) from the TPC-H tools suite using Visual Studio 2022 from my assignmentInstallation guide from my assignment, but I keep running into an error: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: obj".
error image
I'm working with a .vcproj project file (from TPC-H Tools v3.0.1) that I downloaded from the TPC website.
I recently installed Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition, and have "Desktop development with C++" installed.
1.Started by clicking on Open a project or solution
2.Navigated to TPC-H V3.0.1\dbgen and opened tpch.vcproj
Has anyone faced a similar "Value cannot be null" error when working with older .vcproj files in Visual Studio 2022?
Visual Studio prompted me to upgrade the project file, which I did, but the error persists.

What version of MSVS was the project initially created for ?

VisualStudioProject
ProjectType="Visual C++"
Version="8.00"
Name="dbgen"
ProjectGUID="{659CDC00-AE59-4839-B79E-93A846C8FDA2}"
I just checked, and the project file indicates it was originally created with Visual Studio 8. Does this mean I should be taking any specific steps to ensure compatibility with Visual Studio 2022?

Visual C++ 8 is about 2005 - 2006, if it won't convert there is probably no chance.  Create a new project, add the files to it, open the old project in a text editor and look for any compilation options like defines.  Probably want to build it as a 32-bit 1st.
